# How to show only months with data in a bar chart excel

Tags: excel, charts

```
Cash    Comp
```

Jun-13  $121,112    $123,022

Jul-13  $116,289    $89,661

Aug-13  $94,718     $75,898

Jun-14  $108,699    $135,293

Jul-14  $109,685    $122,862

Aug-14  $84,161     $87,540

So I have data that shows like this in excel I want to do a bar chart that shows the difference but for some reason excel includes months that I'm not including in my data ex:(Sept-13, Oct-13, etc .....)  My question is how do I stop excel from doing that and only showing the months I will like to include?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Column A looks like a date to Excel then it will format the x-axis of a graph to show time linearly. That's a sensible assumption. If you want to undermine that assumption by plotting just the months in the data range then reformat the "dates" as strings.

One way to do that is insert a new Col B with a formula like `=text(a2,"mmm-yy")` and use that as the series for the x-axis.